# Ответы, помеченные решением, не могут быть удалены?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, ответы, принятые-ответы

Несколько раз поднимал тревогу на [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471803/8766), а реакции от модераторов до сих пор не последовало. Это не только не ответ на заданный вопрос, тут банальная ошибка в рассуждениях.

Или я чего-то не понимаю?
Ответ помеченный решением не может быть неправильным?

Comment: [Что делать, если принятый ответ — ошибочный или вредоносный?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/961)

Comment: Дело в том, что модератор может быть недостаточно компетентен в теме, чтобы понять из дискуссии как исправить ответ. Если вы считаете, что ответ можно исправить/улучшить и автор не против - внесите правку сами.

Comment: Поднимите рейтинг проголосовавших. Это бред: голосовали либо новички в с++, либо не прочитав вопрос. Сам вопрос C++ касается косъвенно, это реверсинг, ассемблер, на худой конец.

Answer (score 5):

Ответ принимает автор вопроса. Если он (ответ) решил проблему автора, то всё в порядке. "Неверны в рассуждениях", или "мне не нравится этот ответ" не могут стать причинами для удаления.

Тревога поднимается только тогда, когда ответ или вопрос страдают непоправимым контентом или же каким-то образом нарушают политику сайта.

Вам же, в случае неправильного ответа, остаётся поставить минус, написать комментарий под ответом о том, что именно неверно и написать собственное решение вопроса в своём ответе.

Comment: Очевидно же, что проблему решил не ответ, а дискуссия, развернутая под вопросом, в комментариях. Проблема не в том, что мне ответ не нравится, а в том, что **создается иллюзия, что вопрос решен**. Очевидно так же, что в качестве дополнительных ответов здесь должны быть приведены методики реверсинга.

Comment: @mega, я думаю, что никто не будет против, если вы отредактируете ответ и добавите в него ключевые моменты дискуссии из комментариев. Это будет даже здорово.

Comment: @LEQADA, тот ответ не подлежит исправлениям. Хотя бы на том основании. что его автор собирался искать "**функцию**" `offsetof()`

Answer (score 5):

Не надо рассматривать "галочку" как абсолютную истину — это всего лишь ответ, который по той или иной причине понравился или пригодился автору вопроса. В равной степени и оценка — не абсолютная истина, а отражение полезности или интересности вопроса всеми посетителями. Ошибки случаются и там, и там, и система не предполагает права отдельных пользователей решать за остальных, что такое хорошо и что такое плохо.

"Ответ плохо отвечает на вопрос" — это не причина для удаления, и никогда ей не была. И уж тем более вредно применять её для ответов, которые отмечены и галочкой, и положительными оценками. Если ответ плохой, неверный и так далее, то следует минусовать его и объяснять свою оценку в комментариях. Но удалять — нет. А в идеале следует добавить свой правильный ответ. Со временем, если он будет ползен остальным, он всплывёт вверх.

Итак, *если ответ — это честная попытка автора ответить с соблюдением всех правил, то удалять его нельзя*.

Comment: Как-то вы передергиваете. Почитайте ответ и вопрос. Они не имеют ничего общего, кроме возможно термина "оффсет". Т.е. я к тому, что если бы ответ не был помечен галочкой, он скорее всего был бы удален по причине "не ответ на вопрос" и "честная попытка автора" его бы не спасла, т.к. нужно давать ответы хотя бы в тематике вопроса.

Comment: @mega "Не ответ" — это когда участник, *не разбирающийся  теме*, видит, что ответ не отвечает на вопрос. Если это не настолько очевидно, то это ответ. Своим желанием оставить только идеально релевантные ответы вы можете уничтожать информацию, которая кому-то пригодится. Скажем, бывают полезны решения не на той технологии, которая нужна автору, не тем способом, который хочет автор, но которые кому-то *в похожей ситуации* тем не менее помогают. Не стоит увлекаться чисткой полезной информации.

Comment: Вы сейчас защищаете идею совершенно противоположную идеи SO. Как раз, ответов, *неразбирающихся в теме* можно найти на любом классическом форуме. Авторитет SO как раз в том, что его ответы должны быть компетентные. А галочка означает, что это **именно ответ на вопрос**. Не надо придумывать бредни про "абсолютную истину". Сама суть SO в том, чтобы получить **правильный ответ**. Нужно стремиться повышать "качество", а не "количество". Количество у нас уже давно хватает.

Comment: @mega Кто сказал, что на СО должны быть только идеальные и самые правильные ответы? Суть СО в том, что отвечают все и как могут, а остальные пользователи галками и плюсами-минусами выбирают ответы, которые им больше нравятся. Главное, чтобы сверху в числе самых заплюсованных ответов был ответ, который может помочь зашедшему на эту страницу программисту. Ни компетенция, ни абсолютная истина тут вообще не при чём. Вы слишком идеализируете сайт. Здесь *by design* принято, что в галках и плюсах могут быть ошибки, и модераторам запрещено исправлять галки за юзеров в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Суть SO в том, чтобы получить правильный ответ на вопрос. Он может быть не идеальным, но **правильным**, насколько сообщество разбирается в тематике. Ответов может быть сколько угодно, но решение (то, что наверху, с галочкой) должно быть **правильным**. Только в этом вся суть SO, все остальное - рейтинги, теги и т.п. даже не стоит рядом с этой основной идеей. Все остальное - только инструменты для достижения основной цели.

Comment: @mega Поясню: в 99 случаях из 100 даже ромб не имеет права дёргать галочку. Та же история с конкурсами — их нельзя отменять. Просто таковы правила сайта. Это идёт вразрез с идеей предоставлять максимально точную информацию, но правила есть правила. Почему они такие — я могу лишь догадываться. Скорее всего, чтобы избежать бесконечных споров вокруг того, где поставить галочку. Когда галочку ставит один человек, проблемы нет. Повторяю: таковы правила. Они действуют во всём Stack Exchange. Их менять не будут. Поэтому вам придётся смириться с тем, что галочки могут стоять на неверных ответах.

Comment: @mega Что касается конкретно этого вопрос и конкретно этого ответа, то правильным решением в рамках существующих правил будет написать правильный ответ. Возможно, автору он понравится больше, и он переставит галочку. Но даже если не переставит, а ваш ответ хороший, то со временем ваш ответ соберёт больше плюсов, чем "неверный" ответ, и проблема тоже будет решена.

Comment: Дело не в плюсах, и не в моем ответе, который тоже дает решение, но с другой стороны. К тому же, он был дан еще до дискуссии, из которой выяснилось, что нужно ТС. Конечно, со временем все встанет на свои места, кроме галочки и позиции этого ответа в топе. В конце концов, кто-нибудь даст инструкцию для чайников по реверсингу, которая быть может наберет кучу голосов и встанет позади ответа *не втеме*. Думаю, в таких случаях надо просто снимать галку, и можете успокоиться, SO попадет в этот 1 из 100 случаев, т.к., "Все остальное - только инструменты для достижения основной цели".