# Ответы без вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ответы

Причиной этого вопроса послужило 2 события:

- появилась активность по тегу [winapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi)
- и на мете [разгорелась дискуссия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2286/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ruso) по поводу ответов, которые после уточнений вдруг перестали удовлетворять исходному вопросу.

**Собственно вопрос:** что делать с ответами, которые перестали отвечать на вопрос, но могут отвечать на какой-то другой, вновь заданный вопрос?

Сразу привожу свой же пример: [низкоуровневый GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/351045/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-gui)

С одной стороны, ответ можно просто удалить. Но сейчас вот родилась идея: а почему бы не помечать такие ответы определенным тегом и дать возможность сообществу находить для таких ответов свои вопросы?

Я это все веду к тому, что все равно не стану заморачиваться и создавать для своего ответа новый вопрос ([как предлагает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2292/8766) @Nicolas Chabanovsky), мне проще его удалить. Но может, кто-то случайно наткнется на такой вопрос, или решит создать его сам, с помощью такой системы поиска (по аналогии с фильтром "без ответа")?

Вобщем, предложение вношу, пишите отзывы, может кто-то еще предложит варианты, не один же я такой лентяй )

---

Кстати, да, ответы помечать тегами нельзя. Не знаю, как тут теперь дела обстоят технически. По всей видимости, для `ruSO` движок теперь `read-only` и взывать к такому его апгрейду бессмысленно. Но можно, например, добавлять тег в сам вопрос, а в конце текста вопроса вешать какой-то стандартный бейдж со списком ответов, которые "хотят найти свой вопрос".

Это, кстати, даст возможность пользователям `SO` понимать, какие ответы на **конкретный, данный вопрос** следует игнорировать, чтобы не стать заложником различных, как теперь уже выясняется, обстоятельств "с галочками".

---

Сейчас понял, что аналогично дела обстоят и [с этим ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471745/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5asm/471803#471803), по поводу которого я поднимал [отдельную дискуссию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1975/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B).

Comment: IMHO как раз те, кто озабочен поиском ответа на свой вопрос меньше всего будут смотреть на "бесхозные" ответы.

Comment: Ну, это уже их дело. Не так важно, где будет бейдж. Может, лучше его вешать на сам ответ, [как предлагал @VladD](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/962/8766)

Comment: По сути [ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471745/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5asm#471803), так он в самом деле неправильный.  Я бы просто написал это болдом в самом его начале и запретил изменять (если ситема это позволяет). На самом деле на данный вопрос нет ответа, точнее -- `никак, поскольку точно смещение узнает только сам компилятор в то время, когда компилирует этот класс`.

Comment: Понятно, что на этот вопрос ответ неправильный. А что если вопрос будет точно таким же, но без какого-либо упоминания об асме (и без кода, в том числе)? Допустим, когда ответ найдет свой вопрос, автор просто поправит свои ошибочные домыслы, под давлением комментов.

Comment: Так и думал, что после упоминания на Мете кто-нибудь заминусует мой вопрос про GUI. Мелочь, а неприятно.

Answer (score 5):

> что делать с ответами, которые перестали отвечать на вопрос

Если ответ отвечал на вопрос в какой-то редакции вопроса, то следует откатить *вопрос* на эту редакцию (если новых ответов не было добавлено, которые не отвечают на старый вопрос).

Автору оригинального вопроса оставить комментарий: **если правка вопроса делает текущие ответы неверными, то её следует публиковать в виде нового вопроса.**

Иначе многие вопросы, в которых есть код с проблемами (большинство на SO), будут редактироваться, чтобы очередную ошибку в коде описать. В коде может быть много ошибок -- исправление одной ошибки не исправляет все ошибки.

Следует подталкивать людей, чтобы они ограничивались одной проблемой на вопрос, что может повысить полезность для будущих читателей. А новые проблемы следует в виде новых вопросов публиковать.

Другая возможная разновидность изменяющихся вопросов -- когда оригинальный вопрос не достаточно однозначен и не хватает деталей, чтобы полезный ответ дать. Любые ответы, которые пытаются угадать мысли автора вопроса, сами виноваты, если они неверно угадали -- но такие ответы не отвечают на исходный вопрос (то есть они уже были неверными). В этом случае не только допустимо, но и приветствуются правки к вопросу, которые его уточняют так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: А в целом согласен с вами.

Comment: Я в основном не вижу, чтобы авторы вопросов подтасовывали формулировки под конкретный ответ (в обсуждении по первой ссылке, скорее - исключение, чем правило). Но я часто вижу дополнения к вопросу **в комментариях к нему**, или к ответу, как в моем случае. Т.е. откатывать тут нечего, не буду я этим заниматься по моральным принципам, да и незачем мне это. Но вот если мне придет уведомление о том, что появился вопрос, который нашел мой ответ, то я скорее всего его подправлю в новом контексте, чтобы он был полезным, либо помечу его снова "бесхозным", если посчитаю таковым.

Comment: @mega: я и не обсуждаю никакие подгонки (где вы это в моём ответе увидели)? Если вопрос уточнили в комментарии, то следует этот комментарий в сам вопрос добавить (вопрос должен быть самодостаточным).

Comment: Вы большую часть ответа описываете ситуацию, когда уточнение находится в самом вопросе, в какой-то из редакций. А я Вам еще раз говорю: я редко вижу такие ситуации. В основном все уточнения в комментариях. И ни кому не надо их переносить в вопрос, разве что Вы этим будете заниматься сами. При том, что автор ответа по Вашей же рекомендации будет откатывать эти редакции, чтобы его ответ ему удовлетворял. Сами-то понимаете, что это бредовая идея?

Comment: @mega: *"я редко вижу такие ситуации"* *"когда уточнение находится в самом вопросе"* -- зайдите на data.stackexchange.com и посмотрите сколько вопросов редактируется. Обычно я прошу автора вопроса, обновить их вопрос, если комментарий содержит информацию, которая может изменить ответ на вопрос (люди, которые задают вопросы, обычно новые на сайте и не знают правил). Иногда (редко) сам переношу из комментариев, если это помогает читать уже существующие ответы. Где вы в моём ответе увидели, что я автору предлагаю откаты делать? (это ответственность опытных участников).

Comment: Про откаты Вы в первом же предложении пишете, остальное - не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: @mega: где вы увидели что я **автору вопроса** предлагаю откатывать? Если это ещё не ясно, то опытные участники могут это сделать.

Comment: Ну да, я понял, о чем Вы. Вот сейчас полезете наверное редактировать ответ, т.к. Вы же не только про **автора** там ничего не указали, но и про **опытных участников** - тоже забыли. И стоило по этому поводу спорить? :)

Comment: @mega: если Вы увидите от меня ответ когда-либо в будущем, то напомните, пожалуйста, об этой дискуссии, чтобы не тратить ни Ваше ни моё время.

Comment: не обещаю, но, думаю, вы и так запомните :)

Answer (score 2):

Удалять ответ не вижу смысла - пусть себе лежит.

Имеет смысл процитировать, на что отвечаешь, но у тебя это уже есть.

А вопрос там вообще какой-то странный - неясно, что там надо, и как помог принятый ответ.

Comment: Думаю, там просто не хватало тега [tag:WinBGIm], ну и предложить ruSO на него пока нечего.